# Adding custom location pin to styled Google map using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add a dropped pin or custom popup window to a styled google map. Every time I tried to add the pin, the map resets to its default colour. Any clues on how to make both work together?

Here's the styling script:

```js
function initMap() {

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it an array of styles,
  // and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
      [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#523735"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9b2a6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dcd2be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ae9e90"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#93817c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a5b076"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#447530"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#fdfcf8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f8c967"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e9bc62"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e98d58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#db8555"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#806b63"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#8f7d77"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#b9d3c2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#92998d"
      }
    ]
  }
],
      {name: 'Styled Map'});

  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
  // to the map type control.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 52.5200, lng: 13.4050},
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: []
    }
  });
  
  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
}
</script>
```

and here's the pin script:

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

If there's a way to add a popup box on the map using javascript only, that would be amazing also. Currently I am mixing js and css, but the website is hosted on cargocollective and the platform deletes the div upon reload sometimes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two functions with same name.

Also in second function you re-create the map that's why colors are reset to default.

```js
function initMap() {

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it an array of styles,
  // and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#ebe3cd"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#523735"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f5f1e6"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#c9b2a6"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dcd2be"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#ae9e90"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dfd2ae"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dfd2ae"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#93817c"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#a5b076"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#447530"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f5f1e6"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#fdfcf8"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#f8c967"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#e9bc62"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#e98d58"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#db8555"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#806b63"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dfd2ae"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#8f7d77"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#ebe3cd"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit.station",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#dfd2ae"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#b9d3c2"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#92998d"
        }]
      }
    ], {
      name: 'Styled Map'
    });

  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
  // to the map type control.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 52.5200,
      lng: 13.4050
    },
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: []
    }
  });

  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');

  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  map.setCenter(myLatLng);
  map.setZoom(4);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
initMap();
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:300px;">
</div>
```